# Setting up MX Records GitHub Pages

Tags: github, mx-record

I recently got an account with a custom after the @ email address. I can send emails from this, but cannot receive them. I am currently hosting my website with GitHub Pages, and am wondering how the MX records work. [Zoho's documentation](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/configure-email-delivery.html) is kinda confusing: I am wondering how to set this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Github Pages doesn't directly have anything to do with your particular question I don't think.

The MX records need to be set as part of your DNS settings (or ZONE file), and therefore are related to your **domain name** rather than necessarily your hosting provider.

Unless your hosting provider also manages your DNS settings (as in my case with DigitalOcean), these settings will typically be managed with your domain registrar (e.g. GoDaddy, 123-Reg.co.uk etc.).

The documentation you link to provides walkthrough tutorials for many domain providers (e.g. GoDaddy etc.), but from what I can remember, you basically have two steps in setting up Zoho (which I also use - and wholeheartedly recommend!):

1. Add a temporary CNAME record to the DNS settings for your domain (using the details provided by Zoho) so that Zoho can verify you have administrative access to the domain record.
2. Add the two MX records to your domain record, again using the details provided by Zoho.

Here is an example set of DNS records containing the two Zoho MX records and the verify CNAME record to help illustrate:

[image: Example DNS Settings using Zoho MX records]

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I'm assuming then that I'd have to have a * DomainName *.com address, not * Name *.github.io web URL, correct? Or can I upload a file to the github repo to use the MX records? Currently, my site is set to a * Name *.github.io URL. From what I'm reading, id need a paid domain for this to work, correct? Thx!

Comment: Well by the sounds of your original question description, you have a custom domain name already (given by what you said about having a custom url after the '@' in your email address? Whilst I've never really used Github Pages,  I'm pretty sure that you will need a custom domain name managed by some form of registrar in order to set up the MX records.

Comment: I have a .github.io URL right now. My email is with that github.io domain. So, in order to get a working MX record setup, I will need a purchased domain thru a registrar. Bummer. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No worries.  If you need any other help with this then comment below.  If this answer has helped,  it would be great if you could mark is as the accepted answer for your question.  Many thanks.